# How to add phone number claim on IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, identityserver4

I am using IdentityServer4 IDP with a blazor client. In a razor component I have:

```
[CascadingParameter]
public Task<AuthenticationState> AuthenticationStateTask { get; set; }

async Task GetClaims()
{
    var claims = (await AuthenticationStateTask).User.Claims;
}
```

This gives me a total of 9 claims including `sub`, `name`, `preferred_name`, `amr`, `email`, `email_verified` etc. I want to also get the phone number here but it is not present even though I add phone scope in the IDP config as following

```
public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> Ids =>
    new IdentityResource[]
    {
        new IdentityResources.OpenId(), // sub
        new IdentityResources.Profile(), // givenName, familyName ..
        new IdentityResources.Email(),
        new IdentityResources.Phone()
    };
```

and in Client object;

```
AllowedScopes = {
    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Phone,
    "exampleapi" },
```

Doesn't this mean that the phone number should be in the identity token? What should I do to get the phone number?

Also, what is the best way to send a `phoneNumberUpdate` request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client Oidc service registration also needs to be configured to ask for phone scope

```
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
    //...
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("phone");
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The [spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ScopeClaims) says:

> The Claims requested by the profile, email, address, and phone scope
> values are returned from the UserInfo Endpoint, as described in
> Section 5.3.2, when a response_type value is used that results in an
> Access Token being issued. However, when no Access Token is issued
> (which is the case for the response_type value id_token), the
> resulting Claims are returned in the ID Token.

See [UserInfo Endpoint](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints/userinfo.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, IdentityServer4's documentation gives barely any information. And OpenId specification doesn't say anything aspnet specific.

Comment: Glad you found a solution.